# poetry command not found after installing it on jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to build a python package using poetry, here is the stage command to install poetry on the Jenkinsfile

```
stage('poetry'){
  steps {
    sh 'curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3'
    sh 'export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"'
    sh 'poetry --version'
  }
}
```

But I get this output error during the build

```
sh
+ curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org
+ python3
Retrieving Poetry metadata

The latest version (1.4.0) is already installed.
[Pipeline] sh
+ export PATH=/var/lib/jenkins/.local/bin:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/retina3/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
+ PATH=/var/lib/jenkins/.local/bin:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/retina3/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
[Pipeline] sh
+ poetry --version
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/retina3@tmp/durable-deb083f7/script.sh: line 1: poetry: command not found
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Each `sh` command starts its own shell session.  So any variables you set in one session won't be available in another session.  Instead set the variable and execute the command in the same session.

```
sh 'export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"; poetry --version'
```